# How to specify ExpirationTime for SchedulePublish in MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have two scenarios:

1. I would like to schedule a message but if it was not handled until tomorrow this message has to be deleted.
2. I would like to schedule a recurring message (for instance every hour) but if it was not handled in 25 min after publication (all consumers are busy), this message has to be deleted.

I found `ConsumeContext.ExpirationTime` but can't figure out how to set it for a single `SchedulePublish` command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to achieve what you want with `MassTransit`, but at least to can add publication time to a message and check in a handler whether it was published no more than 24 hours (25 minutes) ago. If it is old simply don't handle the message.

Comment: I think this will work, but I expect this functionality integrated.

Comment: It can be done in some king of middleware before the message gets to a consumer. Sure it's better if MT can do it for you. I'm looking forward to see how it is possible to do too.

Comment: And one more point, if it is a recurring message it's impossible to get to know the time when it was sent therefore it's impossible to skip it.